# What does the AND gate do to prevent electrical current?

Tags: current, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I’ve been learning about Boolean algebra and I’m curious as to why 0 AND 1 is 0. In a computer’s circuit, I’m imaging 1 being electrical current flowing through the circuit, and 0 being no current is there. 1 meaning “something”, 0 meaning “nothing”.

Internally, what does the AND gate do to prevent electrical current from flowing through the gate even if there’s some current coming in from one side of the circuit?

Comment: A complete explanation would be long however, you can learn from some useful videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SW2Bwc17_wA
Let us know if you still have some confusion. I would be happy to help since this was the question that bothered me too. I would also recommend you building logic gates on breadboard or any simulation software. It will clear all your doubts.

Comment: Current-mode logic is uncommon; it's more common to see voltage as your logic signal. Either zero volts or some positive voltage to signify zero or one.

Comment: `1 being electrical current flowing` ... that can actually be incorrect ... 1 is usually a particular level of voltage, usually +V such as +5 V or + 3.3 V ... 0 is usually 0 V

Comment: @JaySabir thanks so much! I will check that out

Comment: @jsotola that makes sense, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @JaySabir just ordered some transistors and an electronics kit to make my own logic gate :-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what technology the AND gate is built with. The transistors are used as switches. CMOS technology uses MOSFET transistors which use voltage as the switch control, but other technologies can use current, such as LSTTL with BJT transistors.

If the AND gate is made with BJT transistors, it will have two transistors in series, and both must be on to have current on output. It's basically same as having two light switches in series, as the light will turn on only if both light switches are on.

Comment: This was an extremely helpful complement to @user287001 s answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Boolean algebra is an abstraction. Mathematician Claude Shannon published in 1937 a mathematically sound presentation how relay circuits could be described with Boolean algebra and how a circuit could be constructed if its function is at first described with Boolean algebra. I guess someone before him has noticed the same, but Shannon's writing was a solid academic work and became famous.

Shannon's AND was two switches in series.

[image]

The truth value of a boolean expression presents if there's a conductive way for current.

Since 1950's logic circuits have used different analogy between the truth value and electrical conditions. Typically the truth value presents the voltage level a circuit node is connected to with transistors or fets. If our logic circuit works with +5VD the state of a node is "true" or "1" or "High" if it's connected to +5V and the state is "false" or "0" or "Low" if the node is connected to Ground (=0V).

You should learn how logic circuits were constructed of diodes, resistors and transistors before digital integrated circuits. Computers became popular in 1950's due the availability of transistors, but before the availability of integrated circuits logic circuits were built of discrete parts.

This article [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor–transistor_logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) presents how resistors and transistors have been used to build logic gates. This article [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode–transistor_logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode%E2%80%93transistor_logic) shows how diodes can be used with transistors.

These logic circuit principles (=RTL and DTL) used as few transistors as possible. The output nodes were typically connected actively (=with transistor) to the ground for "0", state "1" was made passively by pull-up resistor if the transistor between the output and ground was not conducting.

Later engineers noticed that in integrated circuits resistors and diodes cost as much as transistors, so it was well profitable to increase the number of transistors to reduce the number of other parts. The benefits were a substantial reduction in power dissipation and increased speed.

TTL [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor–transistor_logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) was the first general purpose logic IC family where this idea was applied. It appeared in 1964. TTL logic ICs are still available in 2020.

Comment: This cleared a lot of confusion up for me with the diagram. Thanks so much. I will check those links out

Answer (score 1):

> I’ve been learning about Boolean algebra and I’m curious as to why 0 AND 1 is 0.

[image]

*Figure 1. A CMOS AND gate. Image source: [All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/cmos-gate-circuitry/).*

You can see here that the input transistors are field-effect transistors (FETs). The gates are insulated from the drain and source as indicated by their symbols so current from the input doesn't conduct through to the output. You can read about their operation in the article linked above.

*I misread this part of the question initially so you can consider the remainder of the answer as supplemental information.*

---

We had to pick some standard. 1 > 0 so we also call them HIGH and LOW, True and False or +5V and 0V (depending on the logic voltages).

> In a computer’s circuit, I’m imaging 1 being electrical current flowing through the circuit, and 0 being no current is there. 1 meaning “something”, 0 meaning “nothing”.

This isn't quite correct. We'll look at the output stage of a logic gate (and ignore whether it's an AND, OR, NOT, NOR, NAND or XOR).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff4rM1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Various configurations using switches rather than transistors or FETs.*

- In (a) the upper switch is closed so the output is pulled HIGH or logic 1. No current flows because there is no load on the output.
- In (b) the lower switch is closed so the output is pulled LOW or logic 0. No current flows because there is no load on the output.
- In (c) the load, R1, is connected between the output and ground. As shown SW5 is closed so the output is high and the logic output will supply current to R1.
- In (d) the load, R2, is connected between the positive supply and the output. As shown SW7 is closed so the output is high. Since both ends of R2 are at V+ no current will flow.

You should be able to work out what happens in (c) and (d) when the upper switches are opened and the lower ones closed.

---

Two more points:

1. If both switches are open the output is disconnected giving a third possibility. Outputs which can do this are called tri-state outputs.
2. We never close the upper and lower switches simultaneously as this will short-circuit the V+ to ground causing high currents to flow and possibly destroying the chip.

Comment: I agree that the two switches you draw represent the typical output stage of a CMOS gate in a discrete package, like a CD4001. But in their simplest VLSI form the NAND and NOR would not have an "output stage", and the other gates can have different implementations.

Comment: It's worse than that, @Elliot! I completely misunderstood the question. I've done a fix. I considered TTL, etc., but decided the answer would be too broad. Feel free ...

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! I’m a software engineer with a very high level understanding of electrical engineering, so this went way over my head, but I’m going to defer back to it once I do some more research.